# SQl query to select relational data

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I am trying to write the SQL that selects all `products` and available `features`.

My database is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_weight` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `product_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
  `feature_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feature_uri` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `feature_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `feature_title` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_body` text,
  `feature_body_short` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `feature_uri_UNIQUE` (`feature_uri`),
  KEY `parentFK` (`feature_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `feature_name_FT` (`feature_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `feature_body_FT` (`feature_body`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_products` (
  `feature_product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feature_product_order` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feature_product_standard` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `feature_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_product_id`),
  KEY `productFK` (`product_id`),
  KEY `featureFK` (`feature_id`)
);
```

I would like to be able to do this in one loop e.g:

```
{foreach}
<tr>
    <td>{name}</td>
    <td>{weight}</td>
    <td>{if product_id == 1}yes{/if}</td>
    <td>{if product_id == 2}yes{/if}</td>
etc
<tr>
{/foreach}
```

I am using Zend, if this can be of use.

Trying to achieve this HTML:
[image: example]

UPDATE:

Non of the suggested answers are working, instead I managed to hack it to work like this:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  (
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature_id SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM feature_products fp
      LEFT JOIN features f ON f.features_id = fp.feature_id
    WHERE fp.product_id = p.product_id
    LIMIT 1
  ) as features
FROM product p
```

Although the problem with the above code is that it does not return 'feature_product_standard'

Comment: Is your schema correct? From your example HTML the weight seems to be associated with a feature but in your schema the weight is associated with a product?

Comment: Am I missing something? If you want feature_product_standard, then add it to the select list, the query as you have it now will only return columns from the 'p' table and CSV list of feature_ids.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want the query to return: all products, for each product a sub list of features with the extra feature_product_standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have MySQL, dunno about Zend, but this should get you started.

```
SELECT 
  p.product_name
  , p.product_description
  , p.product_weight
  , p.product_price
  , p.product_image
  , GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature_id ORDER BY f.feature_id) as feature_ids
  , GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature_name ORDER BY f.feature_id) as feature_names
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN feature_products fp ON (fp.product_id = p.product_id)
LEFT JOIN features f ON (f.feature_id = fp.feature_id)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: You'd need to post-process this but it would work assuming all features are present in at least one product (or at least all the features you want to display!)

Comment: @liquorvicar, or you can run a query first that will get all the features, so you can cache that data. Then you only have to get the id's and put fill the grid using those.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly and only returns 1 product with a lot list of duplicate. See updated answer

Comment: @JohnMagnolia, yep forgot to add a `group by` clause, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not very good code i know, but i hope it helps.
This is using Johan's SQL code.

I haven't tested this.

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Connection info here");

$query = "SELECT 
      p.product_name
   , p.product_description
  , p.product_weight
  , p.product_price
  , p.product_image
  , GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature_id ORDER BY f.feature_id) as feature_ids
  , GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature_name ORDER BY f.feature_id) as feature_names
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN feature_products fp ON (fp.product_id = p.product_id)
LEFT JOIN features f ON (f.feature_id = fp.feature_id)";

$result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);

while ($data[] = odbc_fetch_array($result));

odbc_close($connection);

if ($data[0]["product_name"]) {
echo "<table><tr>";

foreach (array_keys($data[0]) as $a) { $message .= "<th>".$a."</th>"; }
foreach ($data as $d) {
if ($d["product_name"]) {
if ($d) {
echo "</tr><tr>\n";
foreach ($d as $s) {

echo "<td>".$s."</td>";
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly and only returns 1 product with a lot list of duplicate. See updated answer